# ¿Como mantener una variable actualizada sin refrescar en php?

Tags: php, html

Estoy trabajando un proyecto de una pagina de subastas y tengo una situación en la que quiero que cada vez que un usuario coloque una nueva oferta se actualice el valor de la variable que muestra la ultima oferta, para quienes estén en esa pagina, sin necesidad de refrescar.... para evitar incomodidades. Me gustaría saber el nombre del método que se utiliza para hacerlo, no es necesario un ejemplo concreto pero si es posible lo agradezco.

Comment: Hola, sin actualizar no conozco, lo que si es posible es modificar el HTML usando Javascript, tendrías que crear una función que te permita modificar el valor de lo que quieres.

Comment: La tecnología a emplear sería `WebSockets` , sería bueno que investigará sobre esto. Igual su pregunta está calificada para ser cerrada por demasiado amplia o porque se basa principalmente en opiniones.

Comment: te recomiendo utilices JQuery AJAX para mantener "actualizada" para que esta cambie automáticamente... puedes configurar el tiempo de recarga

Comment: Ya que pretendes hacerlo en PHP lo que buscas se llama `Long polling`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con AJAX el valor se va a actualizar cada X milisegundos; los que tú le digas. Con WebSockets el valor se va a actualizar casi instantáneamente. Con AJAX y jQuery puedes tener solucionado el problema en 10 o 15 minutos o menos. Con WebSockets tendrás que aprender primero cómo funciona. No conozco ninguna librería que lo encapsule de forma sencilla, aunque no me extrañaría que la hubiese. Si te decantas por WebSockets podrás añadir otra herramienta a tu currículum de desarrollador web :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una función asíncrona en javascript que se llame cada x tiempo, por ejemplo 200 milisegundos, la cual incluya una llamada ajax al servidor que pregunte por el valor de la variable. La cual convendría que se guardase en un campo de la base de datos.